# Fancybox thumbnail without first image

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have a fancybox gallery with thumbnail helper like this:

```
<a class="fancybox-thumbs" data-fancybox-group="thumb-1" href="img1.jpg">
    <img src="img1.jpg"/>
</a>
<a class="fancybox-thumbs" data-fancybox-group="thumb-1" href="img2.jpg" style="display: none">
    <img src="img2.jpg"/>
</a>
<a class="fancybox-thumbs" data-fancybox-group="thumb-1" href="img3.jpg" style="display: none">
    <img src="img3.jpg"/>
</a>
```

So I keep just the first image visible and hide the other. When the first image is clicked on, it opens the gallery, with thumbnail showing all the three images.

I want to remove the first image from the gallery (and from the thumbnail). So when I click on it, it opens the gallery but just with the "img2" and "img3".

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

First, if you are going to hide some images, then they don't have to have a thumbnail. Just wrap their anchors in a hidden container like

```
<div style="display:none">
    <a data-fancybox-group="thumb-1" class="fancybox-thumbs" href="img2.jpg"></a>
    <a data-fancybox-group="thumb-1" class="fancybox-thumbs" href="img3.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

**Notice** we are just wrapping images 2 and 3 since 1 will be visible.

Second, remove the *class* `fancybox-thumbs` from the image 1 as well as the `data-fancybox-group="thumb-1"` *attribute* since this image won't be part of the gallery but the trigger. Then set a different *class* for it and keep the thumb like :

```
<a class="fancyboxTrigger" href="img1.jpg"><img src="imgThumb1.jpg" alt=""/></a>
```

And bind a `click` event to this image that will trigger the fancybox gallery like :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".fancyboxTrigger").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // prevents to follow the link of first image
        $(".fancybox-thumbs").fancybox({
            // fancybox API options
        }).eq(0).trigger("click");
    })
}); // ready
```

**Notice** that we bound and chained the `.fancybox()`, `.eq()` and `.trigger()` methods to the `.fancybox-thumbs` selector.

Also notice that `.eq(0)` targets the first element of the gallery (indexes in javascript start from `0`)

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hvdn1g2z/)**

**Last note** : If you want the first anchor to trigger the gallery without a thumbnail, just replace the `<img>` tag by a text like

```
<a class="fancyboxTrigger" href="img1.jpg">Open fnacybox gallery</a>
```